# Is each slower than while in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, while-loop, each, benchmarking

The following two functions, which check if a number is prime:

```
def prime1?(prime_candidate)
  return true if [1, 2].include? prime_candidate
  range = 2.upto(Math.sqrt(prime_candidate).ceil).to_a
  i = 0
  while i < range.count
    return false if prime_candidate % range[i] == 0
    range = range.reject { |j| j % range[i] == 0 }
  end
  true
end

def prime2?(prime_candidate)
  return true if [1, 2].include? prime_candidate
  range = 2.upto(Math.sqrt(prime_candidate).ceil).to_a
  range.each do |i|
    return false if prime_candidate % i == 0
    range = range.reject { |j| j % i == 0 }
  end
  true
end
```

yield the following benchamrking result when testing with a very large prime (5915587277):

```
              user     system      total        real
prime1:    2.500000   0.010000   2.510000 (  2.499585)
prime2:   20.700000   0.030000  20.730000 ( 20.717267)
```

Why is that? Is it because in the second function `range` does not get modified by the `reject`, so the `each` is iterating over the original long `range`?

Comment: Yes - the range being iterated over won't change in your each case. The variable points at the new value but that doesn't matter, since you already called each on the original value

Comment: Minor nit - 1 is not a prime number

Comment: You are absolutely correct.

Comment: `i` is never incremented.

Comment: The methods are not equivalent: `prime1` loops 7,561 times and `prime2` loops 76,912 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `range=range.reject {..}`, you don't modify the parent range (which you shouldn't do, because it would mess up the iteration--you need `reject!` to do that) but rather construct a temporary array which only gets assigned to the parent range variable at the end of the iteration.

The `each` iteration in `prime2` runs over the whole original range, not the shortened which, before the loop ends, only exist in the block.

The while version modifies the original array and is therefore quicker (BTW, you realize that i remains zero and it's the `range.count` that changes (decreases) in that while condition and that reject iterates over the WHOLE array again--even the beginning where there couldn't possibly be any more nonprimes to reject).

You'll get a much faster result if you improve the logic of your code. That array manipulation is costly and for this, you don't even need an array:

```
def prime3?(prime_candidate)
  return false if prime_candidate==1
  return true if prime_candidate==2
  range = 2..(Math.sqrt(prime_candidate).ceil)
  range.all? {|x|  prime_candidate % x !=0 }
end #about 300× times as fast for your example as prime1? on my PC
```